# How to show progressbar while generating Excel sheet with data in C#

Tags: c#

i m trying to show progress bar while writing data to excel sheet. but could not show it.

```
           try
           {
            ShowProgressBarForExcelSheet();
            i18NText = I18N.Xlate("PREPARING_EXCEL_SHEET", "Excel-Tabelle ist immer vorbereitet...", null, Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
            oProgressBarFO.UpdateLogSearchStatus(i18NText);

            workSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)excelWorkBook.Sheets[1];
            excel.ActiveSheet.Cells[headerRow, 1] = "Datum/Zeit";
            excel.ActiveSheet.Cells[headerRow, 3] = "Arbeitsplatz";
            excel.ActiveSheet.Cells[headerRow, 5] = "Benutzername";
            excel.ActiveSheet.Cells[headerRow, 7] = "Aktion";
            excel.ActiveSheet.Cells[headerRow, 9] = "Zugriffstype";
            excel.ActiveSheet.Cells[headerRow, 11] = "Klartext";
            excel.ActiveSheet.Cells[headerRow, 13] = "Objekt Type";
            excel.ActiveSheet.Cells[headerRow, 15] = "Patienten-Nr.";
            excel.ActiveSheet.Cells[headerRow, 17] = "Fall-Nr.";
            excel.ActiveSheet.Cells[headerRow, 19] = "Vorgangs-Nr.";
            excel.ActiveSheet.Cells[headerRow, 21] = "Objekt Value";
          }
```

is there any way to show progress bar while writing data to excel sheet? user cannot edit excel sheet or excel sheet must be disable for user till all the data get populated into excel

Comment: what do you mean with `could not show it` ,and what have you tried? also what are you using, winforms, wpf?

Comment: i m using winform..in which i have bulk of data in grid which in want to export to excel sheet. but while exporting it takes too much time so i want to show a progress bar. while exporting to excel sheet user cannot perform any operation with excel like write or search. and i can't expose much code because m working with an organization

Comment: If you want to make it so the writing is done in the background then I suggest you take a look at the msdn page of the [background worker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the BackgroundWorker for achieving this efficiently. Attached here is a sample that shows how you can do this in C# :

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int ProgressToBeupdated = 100;

        BackgroundWorker WorkerThread = new BackgroundWorker();

        WorkerThread.WorkerReportsProgress = true;

        WorkerThread.DoWork += WorkerThread_DoWork;
        WorkerThread.ProgressChanged += WorkerThread_ProgressChanged;

        WorkerThread.RunWorkerAsync(new object());


    }

    void WorkerThread_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    }

    void WorkerThread_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            (sender as BackgroundWorker).ReportProgress(i);       
        }
    }
```

In this sample, i am using a button and a progressbar control which shows progress after every half a sec (Basically by making the thread to sleep until that as this was only a sample).

So, you can setup the events for DoWork in which you need write data to excel sheet, there in you can you can calculate the percentage after tasks and then use ReportProgress(int percentage) to update the percentage to be shown in the progress bar.

You need to define ProgressChanged event to update the values in progressbar on calling ReportProgress function in dowork event handler.

Answer (score 0):

```
**Displaying progress bar while inserting multiple records to database.**

progressBar1.Maximum = dtTable.Rows.Count;
progressBar1.Value = progressBar1.Minimum;

foreach (DataRow vRow in dtTable.Rows)
{
    //TODO : Your INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE Or any Operation/Execution
    progressBar1.Value++;
}
```