# When a slow calculation is happening in Excel, how can I get the calculation percentage to display in my WinForm?

Tags: c#, excel

I have a WinForms application that does some excel work in the background. As shown in the attached screenshot, Excel shows the calculation completion percentage for large calculations.

[image: Calculation percentage]

I would like to be able to access this live percentage to display on my form like this:

```
...

// Method to update my status label on the form
UpdateStatus("Starting heavy calculation . . .");

// The heavy calculation I'm sending to Excel
Range rngEBOMTotals = sheetMathResults.Range["D2"];
rngEBOMTotals.Formula = "=SUMIF(PLM_EBOM!G:G,Results!A2,PLM_EBOM!O:O)";
sheetMathResults.Range["D2:D" + endRange.End(XlDirection.xlUp).Row].FillDown();

// I would like to access the Percentage complete from Excel and show it in my status label.
UpdateStatus( /* Code to get the percent complete */ );
...
```

Is this possible or practical?

Is there a simpler solution to get the status of a calculation that I'm missing?

I've had no luck in my research.

Comment: `FillDown` won't return until the calculation is complete.

Comment: It's after the formula fills down and start to calculate for all rows that takes a long time.

Comment: See if this helps. https://stackoverflow.com/a/29412879/10408933

Comment: @TerryTyson Thanks for the link, I think that will only help if I'm looping through rows in C# to do the calculations. That would take much too long for my use case although answers on that page could help others.